# Getting "unexpected token" error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, syntax-error, server-side-rendering

I wanted to give a little background first, I was facing the below issue in **SSR React using NextJS**. In my `<head>` I have `<script></script>` tag in which I have multiple `<script>` tags nested containing minified JS code for Google Analytics, Adobe Analytics, etc. To debug the issue, I tried to break it up more and only including one JS code at a time in my outer `<script>` tag like only GA or only Adobe to see where it is breaking.

It works fine when I use `<noscript>` tag and inside it, I have multiple `<script>` tags containing minified JS for GA, AA, etc. But it breaks my purpose, as when page loads Google Tag Assistant does not catch the tags.

To my surprise, when I tried running below a simple JS code (PSB SS) in incognito mode (just to make sure plain browser profile without any extensions/plugins) I get the same error. Even if I try without incognito mode I get the same error for this simple JS code.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

What is the issue here and why am I getting this error?

[image]

Comment: You're entering an entire `<script>` tag in the console. That's HTML. The console only understands JavaScript, so it quite rightly fails at parsing the tag.

Comment: you want to install an addon for injecting your custom scripts inside other pages...

Comment: Why you are using `<script></script>` in Console where only JS is expected?

Answer (score 2):

Java script belongs inside `<script>` tags, but `<script>` tags themselves are HTML, therefore they are not expected, and thats why you get the `Unexpected < token`.

In other words, don't nest `<script>` tags. Removing the outermost Tag should fix the error.

Comment: I already tried this, by injecting separate <script> tags like GA, AA into <head>, but Google Tag assistance does not pick it up.

Comment: I think the you are asking the wrong question. The answer to "What is the issue here and why am I getting this error?" is "Because you are nesting `<script>` tags". The question that you are meaning to ask seems to be "How do I add external scripts and GA with Nuxt JS?"